# How to dynamically set click event in jquery mobile inside a for loop

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Here is my problem.
I want to  dynamically generate `<li></li>` elements inside a for loop.
with click events, which invoke a function called showLessonlist(), and i also want to pass one parameter as loop iterator value(value of index) ,how can i do that ?  i am a beginner, kindly help me,thanks in advance.

my code is here

```
for (var index = 0; index < courseData.Subjects.length; index++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute("data-tab", "1");
        li.setAttribute("vclick",'showLesssonList('+ index +')');
        li.innerHTML = courseData.Subjects[index].Title;
        $('#subjectlisttabs').append(li);
    }
```

i want to invoke `showLessonList()` with respective index value as taking parameter when i click or tap on the `<li>` element generated inside for loop

i am currently developing mobile app with cordova , so kindly suggest me which event should i use `vclick` or `click`, tap, `onclick`.
And kindly show a way to  dynamically set these event inside a loop with respective index value take as my function parameter.
Post replays as earlier as possible. Again thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only the below code: Dynamically associate the click event to the unique identifier of the li in the creation phase itself.

```
 for (var index = 0; index < courseData.Subjects.length; index++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute("data-tab", "1");
        li.setAttribute("id", "subtab_" + index);
        li.innerHTML = courseData.Subjects[index].Title;

        $('#subjectlisttabs').append(li); // adding subject tabs dynamically

        $("#subtab_" + index).off('vclick').on('vclick', function(e) {

            alert("you clicked: " + $(this).attr('id'));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i came up with a solution.

```
function setSubjectTabs() {


        for (var index = 0; index < courseData.Subjects.length; index++) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.setAttribute("data-tab", "1");
            li.setAttribute("id", "subtab_" + index);
            li.innerHTML = courseData.Subjects[index].Title;

            $('#subjectlisttabs').append(li); // adding subject tabs dynamically

            /* var tab = "<li data-tab='1' vclick='showLesssonList(\"" + index + "\")'>" + courseData.Subjects[index].Title + "</li>";
             $('#subjectlisttabs').append(tab); // adding subject tabs dynamically*/
        }

        for (var index = 0; index < courseData.Subjects.length; index++){
            $('#subtab_'+index).tap( createCallback( index ) ); // create a call back method here for dynamic behaviour
        }

        $('#subtab_0').tap(); // by default first tab will be selected
    }

    function createCallback( index ){
        return function(){
            showLesssonList(index);
        }
    }
```

I used a callback functionality.
Please suggest if any better approach than this.